# AWS configuring Auto scaling and cloud watch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cloudwatch

Question related to configuring cloudwatch and auto scaling. 
I have an ec2 instance ( Instance 1 ) hosting a website , of which I have also created an AMI ( Image 1). 
I woud like to configure a system so that when the Instance 1 is completely degraded, I want to start a new instance ( Instance 2 ) from Image 1.
Hence no load balancer is needed  .

Question  . These are the steps I plan to use -
configure autoscaling , with minsize 0 , maxsize 1 
use cloud watch metrics to monitor for statuscheck failed, then terminate the instance 1 and use instance 2

Do i need to configure scale up and scale down policy ? Is the systemCheck failed the right metrcs to monitor for instance failure ?
Do I need to use autoscaling in conjunction with cloudwatch for my scenario ?
Help appreciated.

Thanksa

Answer (score 0):

This question seems antithetical to the typical intended use for scaling, which is to scale services behind a load balancer to AVOID getting service degradation.

The way one would typically utilize the minsize/maxsize in a case like yours would be to have both minsize and maxsize = 1.  In order to spawn a new instance in the autoscaling group, all you would need to do is to terminate the existing instance.  Since the instance count would now be 0, the autoscale would kick in to start a new instance. Of course you are going to have some downtime while the 2nd instance gets ready to accept traffic. But if your first instance is non-responsive anyway, then this may not matter to you.

I personally can not really understand the use case of only having a single instance behind a load balancer other than for testing purposes.  I would always have at least two production instances running behind a load balancer so that if health check fails on one of two instances, the traffic in load balancer would be shifted to the other in short order (much shorter time than it would take to start a new instance and have it ready to accept traffic).

That being said, the autoscaling rules are pretty flexible and you could theoretically do what you want.  See the link below for the AWS documentation on configuring autoslacing policies and tying them to Cloudwatch metrics.  It is pretty straightforward to achieve.

[Here is good example from AWS documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SetUpASLBApp.html)